# How to check where the RDS DB endpoints are stored on EC2 server for RoR web application?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds, ruby-on-rails

I'm a low-code web maintainer in our company.

We are managing a RoR web app based on the Sharetribe Go codebase on AWS EC2+RDS. We have to update RDS DB to MySQL version 8.0 and then connect the EC2 instance to the new RDS DB endpoints.

When we SSH to the prod server and check the config/database.yml file, we see endpoints saved there (on line "host:" ...). But when we SSH to the staging server, that same file did not contain the staging endpoints. So where do I need to go to change the endpoints for the staging server? What are best practices for prod vs. staging?

Note: Our IT team has folded after the epidemic. We are just maintaining it minimally for now.